# How does data: {} or whatever work in Ajax?

Tags: ajax

```
function Autobuy(id, price){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=" + id + "&type=robux&expectedPrice=" + price,
        success: function(Data){
            var link = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=" + id + "&type=robux&expectedPrice=" + price
            var Regex = /__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.+)" \/>/
            var Verify = Data.match(Regex)[1]
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/ProcessPurchase",
                data: //idk what to do here to prevent internal 500 serv error
                __RequestVerificationToken: Verify,
                CurrencyType: 1,
                AssetID: id,
                ExpectedPrice: price
            });
        }
    });
};
```

How do you use data: with $.ajax({ })?
If I don't use data: then it gives me an error in the function I made.

Comment: @sevenseacat POST http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/ProcessPurchase 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

It's the result from your `GET` request, in fact it contains whatever the server returns from it(integer, string, array...) if there are no errors(that's why it's passed as parameter in `success:`).

Comment: I still don't get it to be honest, what would I do with data: to fix the server error?

Comment: Now I get it, you're not talking about `success: function(Data){` part. Sorry, misunderstood.

`data:` is the string of values you pass to the server, like you would see in a URL when you submit a form with `GET` method.

Something like `data1=value1&data2=value2&data3=value3`

Comment: So how would I use data: in the way i'm talking about? What value am I supposed to use data: for?

Comment: It depends on what the server expects.

Comment: No, they don't give you any documents. I just really need to know what value to put so it doesn't give me an error.

Comment: You just can't keep guessing. If you don't know what the server need, then you wouldn't be able to get requests from it. It's like trying to call a person without his phone number :D

Comment: How do I know what the server needs? :c

Comment: There no way other than get this info from them.